# Kibana - How to display log as table

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm testing Kibana 4 for a project.

I have created an index from my database table which is composed by 3 fields:

1. Date
2. User
3. Action

I would like to display my index as a simple table (3 column, N rows) in my dashboard.

I tried to use "Data table" visualization but I can't find a way to display my results without any Metrics (Count, Sum etc...)

Maybe is pretty simple and I missed something... is there a way to do this?

Regards,

Answer (score 174, accepted):

On the Discover tab, create a view that has just the fields you want and then save that as a search.

On the Dashboard tab, click on Edit then hit the `+ Create new` button to add a widget, but if you look at the top, there's a Searches tab.  Select that and add your saved search in.

Comment: Is there any way to down download the raw data which is displayed as table?

Comment: @RamaVadakattu there isn't currently a way to do it within Kibana.

Comment: WOW, I have been looking for this for ages. It's a pitty that I can't change the name of the columns.

Comment: @Alcanzar But it is very limited. We can only manage 100 saved searches in it. But, we would like to have more than 500 nodes of log has to be captured. Any best way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 22):

In Kibana 7.5.0 you can do it as follows:

1. Go to Discover section
   [image]
2. Select fields you are interested in
   [image]
3. Click on Save to save your discover search so you can use it in visualizations and dashboards
   [image]
   [image]
4. Click on Dashboard and create a new dashboard
   [image]
   [image]
5. Click on Add and select the panel
   [image]
   [image]
6. There is no step 6
   [image]

Answer (score 21):

> [Elastic 7.x / 2019 Update]

I was a bit confused when I read @Alcanzar's answer so I am sharing a little more noob-friendly step-by-step how-to here :

- **STEP 1 : Create the Index Pattern**

[image]

- **STEP 2 : Go to the Dashboard view, and create a view on your index**
  Select each column you want to include/add in your view by clicking "add" on it (*The confusing part is that until you do that, you will have a "scrambled" view listing everything in a jumbled way.*)

[image]

- **STEP 3 : Go to the Dashboard view, and create a view on your index**

The trick is to select the specific columns you want to include... and voila !
Don't forget to save your view, this will help a lot in the process.

[image]

Comment: The One-Million dollar question, how to change the column name???

Comment: @FranciscoSouza you would need to update the mapping and probably also reindex your date for that. No easy way around this. You cannot just alter a column name like that in ES. There are a few workarounds if you dig the subject

Comment: How can we apply the conversions(bytes to MB or GB) at data table Columns in kibana?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution has its **pros** (if, for simplicity, you see your index as a table, this is the only way to deal with rows *naturally*) but also **cons** (it allows the user to see too much information, by expanding the records that appear in the table; users cannot get an export of the values).

So if you plan to build tables to use in reports seen by users which should not see everthing and may want to get exports of the data, I recommend a different (hacky) approach using Table visualizations:

Say you have three columns A, B and C:

- If there are no duplicates considering the combined values of A and B, you can use these two vales as aggregation fields, and then set a Max or Top hit Metric for C.
- If even A, B and C have duplicates, then you can use the three of them as aggregation fields and add a Metric count, that will give you the number of repeated rows. This solution makes somehow sense, because instead of repeating the same row 'n' times you just tells you should have repeated 'n' times that row.
- If A and B have duplicates but A, B and C are unique, then there is, afaik, no elegant solution. You have to use the three of them as aggregation fields, but then you would have a dummy metric at the end (e.g. count, always equal to 1).

Why? why do we have to go through all of this? that is another question...

Comment: Why ? Well, Kibana is not *really* and end-user tool. If you need fine-grain access management to filter what end-users can see you would need to isolate ELK through a web front-end that is accessible to them where you serve only what you want them to see, the way you want them to see it

Comment: @MehdiLAMRANI Yes, you are right. But it took us a while to acknowledge that, and I think Elastic's marketing is a bit ambiguous with regards to that specific use-case... What at the end of the day just leads to frustration. And it is a pity, because I don't think Kibana is that far away to being an end-user tool, and that is what the market is asking for, imho.