# ElasticSearch - Kibana raw data chart

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have set-up an elasticsearch server and I am feeding data to it with logstash. My data consists of various numeric fields which are logged through time. I want to create a chart in Kibana that will display the raw data as points, and the average of my data as a line chart on top of that. Pretty much something like the picture below... (This is from Kibana's homepage)

[image: This is what I am trying to achieve, but can't]

I have a real problem displaying the raw values of my data and I cannot find a way to do it in the documentation. Has anybody else encountered the same problem? Is this doable in Kibana?

Comment: Your question is lacking information. What have you done so far, what are your current results, why do they not fit what you want to do and what does your data look like? As your question stand, no one will answer, for lack of information. Perhaps read the guide on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think you are looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29679855/2785358